# How to get the data before the max id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm doing an info system that has announcements, so I wanted to get the data from announce table, first should be the one with max id of course since it is the latest announcement and here is my code for it:

```
SELECT image FROM announce where id=(SELECT max(id) FROM announce);
```

Now I wanted to get the data before the max id and I'm using this code here:

```
SELECT image FROM announce where id=(SELECT max(id)-1 FROM announce);
```

But it only works if there are no deleted rows,if there are some deleted rows it doesn't work like max id is 10 and the id's 9,8,7 are deleted. That means the present id's are: 1,2,3,4,5,6,10, how will I be able to get the data in the id 6,5,4,3,2,1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `ORDER` the query by descending order (`DESC`), and have an `OFFSET` of one (`OFFSET 1`), you would get the second to last row. And offset of two would give the row before that, and so on. This also uses `LIMIT 1`, so we just get one row. `LIMIT 1, 1` is the same as `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1`.

```
SELECT image
FROM announce
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1, 1
```

- [MySQL on `SELECT` statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use one query with `order by` and `limit` instead of the two queries you use:

```
select image 
from announce 
order by id desc 
limit 2
```

In case you want to query them separately, you can change `limit 2` to `limit 1, 1` for you second query to work as you wish.